# Syncing MS Outlook Inbox to Squirrel inbox

Tags: email

I synced my squirrel mail to my ms outlook, but my emails in my inbox in my squirrel mail were lost(empty)

What happened? How can I return the emails from MS outlook to my squirrel mail?

Answer (score 3):

Squirrel Mail is a IMAP web front-end for mail. You need to configure Outlook to use IMAP instead of POP3 and move the emails back to your IMAP inbox.

After doing so, you'll be able to use either program to view your mail.

Comment: How do I return my outlook emails back to the server?

Comment: Drag and drop them.

Comment: drag and drop where?